# What is the association between earth and the fire element?

Tags: creation, universe

In vedic times, Boomi is known as 'Prithvi' and was mother to 'Agni'. [Wikipedia]

Also, some texts refer that Boomi is also mother to planet Mars (Angaraka) who is fiery in nature. [Wikipedia]

Incidentally, Boomi/earth sign Capricorn exalts planet Mars in that sign.

Therefore, what is the connection between Boomi and fire element of the panchabhutas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a relationship between the elements Earth and Fire.  But Fire does not come from Earth, instead Earth comes from Water, and Water comes from Fire. Here is what [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe01/sbe01120.htm) of the Chandogya Upanishad says:

> In the beginning, my dear, there was that only which is (τὸ ὄν), one only, without a second. Others say, in the beginning there was that only which is not (τὸ μὴ ὄν), one only, without a second; and from that which is not, that which is was born. But how could it be thus, my dear? ... How could that which is, be born of that which is not? No, my dear, only that which is, was in the beginning, one only, without a second. It thought, may I be many, may I grow forth. It sent forth fire. That fire thought, may I be many, may I grow forth. It sent forth water. And therefore whenever anybody anywhere is hot and perspires, water is produced on him from fire alone. Water thought, may I be many, may I grow forth. It sent forth earth (food). Therefore whenever it rains anywhere, most food is then produced. From water alone is eatable food produced.

And here is what [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15034.htm) of the Taittiriya Upanishad says

> From that Self (Brahman) sprang ether (âkâsa, that through which we hear); from ether air (that through which we hear and feel); from air fire (that through which we hear, feel, and see); from fire water (that through which we hear, feel, see, and taste); from water earth (that through which we hear, feel, see, taste, and smell). From earth herbs, from herbs food, from food seed, from seed man.

Comment: Keshav, true, I agree with your answer quoting the upanishads. But I am wondering whether Boomi/Booma (devi) being mother of Agni and Mars, is an embodiment of the Agni tattwa. Whenever she is born on earth, be it Sita or Andal, she is always self-incarnate. Even Skanda who is embodiment of Mars the fiery planet, is self-incarnate. Is it because booma/boomi does not want to be cooled down?

Comment: @jrd The origins of planets, the origins of gods of those planets, and the origins of elements are three separate things that don't have too much connection with one another.